# Are Hashtables Serializable?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I see a pervasive [belief](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adam/2010/09/10/how-to-serialize-a-dictionary-or-hashtable-in-c/) (2009 article) throughout the internet that the [`Hashtable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable(v=vs.110).aspx) class is not serializable; however, I cannot find any modern documentation that supports this notion.

The belief stems from another ill-documented belief that the [`IDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea(v=vs.110).aspx) interface prevents serialization; however, I cannot find anything in MSDN that supports this claim, today.

Further, `Hashtable` implements `ISerializable` and contains extension methods that accept serialization information.

So, what's the deal? Is `Hashtable` serializable? Where is the documentation that supports this notion surrounding `IDictionary`?

**Further Clarification** (*please read*):

The statement that `IDictionary` is not serializable is supported by plenty of documentation; however, this focuses on the use of XML-based serialization interactions with a class. `ISerializable` as mentioned both in the comments, below, and through MSDN indicates that a class is serializable. It also means the class the must be responsible for its own serialization.

I think this negates the statement that a Hashtable is not serializable. That is perhaps the genesis of my question.

Comment: There is not a one to one correspondence between "ideas that people have" and "things that are documented."

Comment: @RobertHarvey sure. That's true. But to say something is plainly not serializable should be supported by documentation, especially if this something extends `ISerializable`. This seems like a particularly difficult statement to support considering the availability of such libraries as NewtonSoft.

Comment: It's on [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx): *"The XmlSerializer cannot process classes implementing the IDictionary interface. This was partly due to schedule constraints and partly due to the fact that a hashtable does not have a counterpart in the XSD type system. The only solution is to implement a custom hashtable that does not implement the IDictionary interface."*  (Google is a great tool).

Comment: As per [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adam/2010/09/10/how-to-serialize-a-dictionary-or-hashtable-in-c/), the reason given is "The reason the System.NotSupportedException is thrown is because the IDictionary class implements the IXmlSerializable interface.The IXmlSerializable interface makes us overide the following methods: GetSchema, ReadXml and WriteXml.". 2010 article :)

Comment: @ManoDestra thanks. That's helpful. I read that one, too, earlier. But, I am not sure that prevents `HashTable` from being serialized, due to its implementation of `ISerializable` - which dictates that HashTable: [1] is capable of serialization; and [2] needs to control its own serialization. So, I am surprised that HashTable is labeled as unserializable (if we aren't limiting the process of serilization to XML).

Comment: Putting all the talk of serialization aside - it's 2016, why use `HashTable` at all?

Comment: @JamesThorpe: The `Dictionary` class uses `HashTable` under the covers.  It's faster than a binary tree for large collections, so long as you don't have collisions.

Comment: One thing to note: .NET hashcodes *aren't persistable* by contract, they aren't even guaranteed to be the same in two different application domains, IIRC. So serializing a dictionary or a hashtable can only really save the keys and values, and "manually" reconstructing the hash-ness on the target.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It does?  I thought it used some sort of internal arrays for buckets and an internal class for holding key/value pairs with strict typing etc on it?

Comment: There are many forms of serialization. Some work (BinaryFormatter, Json), some don't (Xml). Is this even relevant in 2016? Don't use the `Hashtable` class at all.

Comment: @JamesThorpe: The Reference Source is [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs).  Line 12 says "Purpose: generic hashtable implementation," though interestingly it doesn't implement `IHashTable` and is serializable.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Oh yes, from that view point it is a hash table.  But it's not a `HashTable`.  It still fails with the xml serialising due to it implementing `IDictionary` (modify Luaans answer below to use one, it fails the same way).  But still, why use the actual `HashTable` class these days - that was my original point.

Comment: @JamesThorpe: I never use one.  I use a `Dictionary`.  And yes, I've encountered the serialization problem on the Dictionary as well.  There's a way to do it; I think you can use a `DataContractSerializer` to get around the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The pervasive belief is so pervasive because it's true:

```
var t = new Hashtable();
t.Add("Hi!", "I'm here");
t.Add("Hm", "Yup");

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Hashtable));

using (var sw = new StringWriter())
{
  serializer.Serialize(sw, t);

  Console.WriteLine(sw.ToString());
}
```

throws

> NotSupportedException: The type System.Collections.Hashtable is not supported because it implements IDictionary.

That doesn't mean that it's *literally impossible to serialize a hash table*. Of course I can just iterate over all the keys and values, write them to a string and then reconstruct the hashtable from that. It's just that I can't use the serialization infrastructure fully.

What's the reasoning here? It's actually quite simple - XmlSerializer is designed to produce good XML, in the spirit of the interchange format XML was designed to be. And XML doesn't have any kind of dictionary or "key-value" mechanism that would fit. So to support hashtable serialization, they'd have to make their own "sub-format" with its own rules. And back when .NET was being designed, this was a huge no-no - XML was an *interchange* format. Any extension (hah) to the format means you're no longer compatible, no matter how good of an idea you have.

Of course, nowadays, everyone and their grandmother are producing XML data that isn't used for interchange purposes. And it's not entirely a bad thing (after all, .NET `config` files are also a XML format). But it's also kind of wrong.

In contrast, take something like `BinaryFormatter`. That's a class where the .NET team designed the whole format, and isn't limited by a standard. And lo and behold - `BinaryFormatter` can serialize and deserialize a `Hashtable` just fine.

So the slightly more correct belief would be "Hashtable cannot be serialized to valid standard XML. The XmlSerializer class in particular will throw an error when you attempt to serialize a Hashtable."

Comment: I'm a former Java developer. I am still getting used to the idea (reinforced here) that a lot of people associate the word "serialization" with the `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: @Thomas It's funny, because when I was starting with Java, everyone associated Xml with everything in Java :P .NET (and the JVM ecosystem too, of course) is very complex, and it has many different goals. Is it a good idea that some objects can be serialized in one way but not another? It definitely makes things look a lot less abstract and bad OOP, doesn't it? And .NET was heavily marketed around web services and SOAP, so the connection to XML makes a lot of sense. `XmlSerializer` is very specific in that it's explicitly designed to make good XML; `BinaryFormatter` has its own format.

Comment: When I left Java, I was using Spring annotations (which under the hood is XML). I've got a personal dislike of XML (nothing more than distaste). But, as a Java J2EE (again annotations made their way in to cover the XML) and, especially, as a JavaScript engineer,  XML and serialization (for me) just aren't as strongly connected. Different generation, maybe?

Comment: @Thomas Well, I've been working with binary serialization long before I first heard of XML, including the fake-y serialization like "take this whole bunch of in-memory C structs and save it to file all at once". And I still use binary serialization for everything that warrants it. It's just that I really got to like XML - it's a well defined format for interop, and in most of my commercial projects, interop is almost the only place we ever used serialization (and a smattering of hand crafted binary formats where critical). I suspect modern programmers will have a similar thing about JSON :)

Answer (score 5):

Does Hashtable implement ISerializable?  Absolutely:

```
public class Hashtable : IDictionary, ICollection, IEnumerable, ISerializable, IDeserializationCallback, ICloneable
```

Can we serializae a Hashtable to XML?  Let's try it:

```
        var hash = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
        hash[7] = "7";
        hash[8] = "8";
        var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(System.Collections.Hashtable));
        TextWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\SomeFile.xml");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, hash);
```

Result... Error as you expected

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Xml.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The type System.Collections.Hashtable is not supported because it implements IDictionary.

So, it would appear that indeed, it's still the case in .Net 4.5+

But lets try one more time with a binary serialization...

```
        var hash = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
        hash[7] = "7";
        hash[8] = "8";
        var formatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\SomeFolder\SomeFile.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
        formatter.Serialize(stream, hash);
        stream.Close();
```

Result... No Errors thrown...  **So the issue appears to be related to IDictionary and XmlSerialization, but not all Serialization**

If you really need to do this to XML, ManoDestra had a nice link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adam/2010/09/10/how-to-serialize-a-dictionary-or-hashtable-in-c/

Also, interestingly, XML Serialization mentions that you can't serialize unsigned longs or collections there-of.

[Microsoft XML Serialization (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Well answered. Thank you for the time and the sources.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft seems to say that it is certainly possible to do this.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b85344hz(v=vs.110).aspx

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

public class App 
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() 
    {
        Serialize();
        Deserialize();
    }

static void Serialize() 
{
    // Create a hashtable of values that will eventually be serialized.
    Hashtable addresses = new Hashtable();
    addresses.Add("Jeff", "123 Main Street, Redmond, WA 98052");
    addresses.Add("Fred", "987 Pine Road, Phila., PA 19116");
    addresses.Add("Mary", "PO Box 112233, Palo Alto, CA 94301");

    // To serialize the hashtable and its key/value pairs,  
    // you must first open a stream for writing. 
    // In this case, use a file stream.
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Create);

    // Construct a BinaryFormatter and use it to serialize the data to the stream.
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    try 
    {
        formatter.Serialize(fs, addresses);
    }
    catch (SerializationException e) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to serialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
        throw;
    }
    finally 
    {
        fs.Close();
    }
}


static void Deserialize() 
{
    // Declare the hashtable reference.
    Hashtable addresses  = null;

    // Open the file containing the data that you want to deserialize.
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Open);
    try 
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        // Deserialize the hashtable from the file and 
        // assign the reference to the local variable.
        addresses = (Hashtable) formatter.Deserialize(fs);
    }
    catch (SerializationException e) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to deserialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
        throw;
    }
    finally 
    {
        fs.Close();
    }

    // To prove that the table deserialized correctly, 
    // display the key/value pairs.
    foreach (DictionaryEntry de in addresses) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} lives at {1}.", de.Key, de.Value);
    }
}
}
```